# Comando para substituir caracteres recursivamente

Tags: regex, recursão, shell

Preciso de um comando que faça a substituição de um padrão específico em cada linha de um arquivo tantas vezes quanto necessárias até que o padrão não seja mais encontrado.

Por exemplo, num arquivo CSV, os campos são separados por ponto-vírgula `;`.
Os campos nulos não possuem caractere, como no arquivo a seguir que representa uma lista de contatos com 3 registros:

```
Nome;Sobrenome;Telefone1;Telefone2;Email
Joao;Silva;9999-8888;9292-9292;joaosilva@email.com
Maria;Souza;8899-0011;;msouza@empresa.com.br
Carlos;Oliveira;;;
```

A primeira linha é o cabeçalho do arquivo. O contato `Maria Souza` possui o `Telefone2` nulo e o contato `Carlos Oliveira` possui nulos os campos `Telefone1`, `Telefone2` e `Email`.

Quero acrescentar `\N` onde o campo é nulo.

No Linux, se utilizo o comando:

```
$ sed -e 's/;;/;\\N;/g' -e 's/;$/;\\N/' arquivo.csv > novo-arquivo.csv
```

O resultado é satisfatório para o registro `Maria Souza`, mas não para o `Carlos Oliveira`, pois ao encontrar o primeiro padrão `;;` e realizando a substituição (`Carlos;Oliveira;\N;;`) ele não considera o texto substituto na continuação da pesquisa e passa já para o próximo padrão, que é o `;$`, ficando o resultado desta maneira:

```
Carlos;Oliveira;\N;;\N
```

Permanecendo um campo nulo ainda.
Gostaria de uma solução tanto Unix quanto para Windows.

Comment: Não considero uma boa ideia tratar um arquivo CSV com uma expressão regular, mas, como você provavelmente já sabe disso e deve estar simplesmente tratando dados para fornecer a outro programa, vou deixar pra lá ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use perl, que [suporta look-ahead](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions):

```
 perl -p -e 's/;(?=;|$)/;\\N/g' arquivo.csv > novo-arquivo.csv
```

Incidentalmente, se quiser fazer a alteração dentro do mesmo arquivo (sem ter que redirecionar pra outro), simplesmente passe a opção -i (*infile*):

```
 perl -p -i -e 's/;(?=;|$)/;\\N/g' arquivo.csv
```

Comment: Muito interessante @elias. Mas este comando que você postou não atende ao último campo do registro se a linha terminar com `;` que significa que o último campo é nulo, devendo ser substituído por `;\N`.  
Eu posso colocar um novo parâmetro `-e`, assim?: `perl -p -e 's/;(?=;)/;\\N/g' -e 's/;$/;\\N/g' arquivo.csv > novo-arquivo.csv`

Comment: @ricidleiv verdade, acabei de corrigir, valeu.

Comment: e no caso, por exemplo, para excluir uma palavra recursivamente numa linha, como a palavra `nulo` na string `nnuloulochavenulnuloo` para sobrar apenas a plavra `chave`. Em Perl, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Bom, nesse caso acho que não teria como escapar dum loop. Provável que o one-liner fique mais bonito em sed, mesmo: `sed ':loop; s/nulo//g; t loop;'` -- difícil bater essa. =)

Comment: Você pode simplificar o caso da linha que termina com `;` se usar `perl -p -e 's/;(?=;|$)/;\\N/g;'`

Comment: @rodrigorgs boa, Rodrigo! vou incorporar a sugestão! -- apesar que fica um pouquinho mais difícil de ler, né?

Answer (score 1):

O comando `sed` do Linux permite trabalhar com rótulos, úteis para trabalhar com recursividade.

Para o exemplo, pode ser utilizado da seguinte forma:

```
$ sed -e ':loop' -e 's/;;/;\\N;/g' -e 't loop' -e 's/;$/;\\N/' arquivo.csv > novo-arquivo.csv
```

---

Lembrando que, se o arquivo foi gerado no Windows e for utilizar o comando no Linux, deverá converter o arquivo do padrão DOS para o Unix, pois o caractere de final de linha é diferente. E vice-versa.

Pode-se utilizar os comandos `dos2unix` ou `unix2dos`.

Comment: A propósito, sed também suporta separar comandos com `;` e alterar diretamente o próprio arquivo, então você poderia fazer: `sed -i ':loop; s/;;/;\\N;/g; t loop; s/;$/;\\N/' arquivo.csv` -- resultado equivalente ao segundo comando perl da minha resposta =)

Answer (score 1):

Estou acostumado com ambientes de desenvolvimento com Java, tanto em Linux quanto em Windows, então eu usaria uma task Ant para executar operações de manipulação de arquivos multiplataforma como esta.

Ant é uma ferramenta poderosa e versátil usada para automação, *builds* (compilação e e montagem de pacotes) e processamento de arquivos. É importante notar que Ant **não é uma linguagem de programação**, como alguns pensam, mas é uma forma de declaração de atividades (*tasks*) que devem ser executadas.

## Instalando o Ant

Baixe o pacote binário [aqui](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi), descompacte-o numa pasta e adicione-o ao `PATH` do seu sistema operacional.

Exemplo no Windows:

```
set path=%path%;c:\caminho\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin
```

## Escrevendo o Ant Build

O seguinte projeto Ant faz a substituição de linhas num dado arquivo:

```xml
<project name="MyProject" default="replace" basedir=".">
    <target name="replace">
        <replaceregexp
                file="${file}"
                byline="true"
                match=";(?=;|$)"
                replace=";\\\\N"
                flags="gs" />
    </target>
</project>
```

## Executando o Projeto

O Ant procura automaticamente por um arquivo chamado `build.xml` no diretório atual. Então, se `file.txt` é o arquivo a ser processado, o comando a seguir irá realizar a substituição:

```
ant -Dfile=file.txt
```

Caso o projeto Ant tenha outro nome, pode-se usar o parâmetro `-f`:

```
ant -f /caminho/meu-build.xml -Dfile=file.txt
```

## Aprendendo mais sobre o Ant

Apenas leia o [manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) por completo.